# Parsing ASCII Text file into 2d Vector of Char's

Tags: c++, parsing, vector

I need help, im trying to read a file that looks something like this:

```
.........
.........
.........
.........
....X....
.........
.........
.........
.........
```

i need to parse this into a 2d vector of chars so i can make modifications to it later.

What ive come up with so far is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
//look up line by line parsing
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    vector<vector<char>> data;
    ifstream myReadFile;
    myReadFile.open("input1.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        int c = 0;
        char currentchar;

        while (!myReadFile.eof()) {
            data[i][c] = currentchar;
            c++;
            currentchar = myReadFile.get();
        }
    }

    //for ()


    myReadFile.close();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Re: `i < data.size()` -- `data.size()` is 0, so the loop body won't be run. Do you know the dimensions of the grid?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values instead of creating them with default constructors and immediately changing them. That is, change `ifstream myReadFile; myReadFile.open("input1.txt');` to `ifstream myReadFile("input1.txt");`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks, im new to c++ ill keep this in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reserve space in the vector before assigning values to it through `data[i][c] = currentchar;`. But it's probably hard to reserve space before having read the contents.

An easier way would be to use the dynamic growth capabilities of vectors (i.e. `push_back`), and to use `std::string` as line content since you can read in complete lines then easily. You can still access/alter the contents then trough `data[i][c] = currentchar;`. See the following code illustrating this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    const char* fileContent = R"foo(.........
.........
.........
.........
....X....
.........
.........
.........
.........)foo";

    std::vector<std::string> lines;
    stringstream ss(fileContent);
    string line;
    while (getline(ss,line)) {
        lines.push_back(line);
    }

    lines[2][5] = 'Y';

    for (auto line : lines) {
        for (auto c : line) {
            cout << c << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
. . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . Y . . . 
. . . . . . . . . 
. . . . X . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . .
```

Comment: thank you! i was able to modify your solution to work with text files input by the user.

Answer (score 0):

You may make life easier by using `std::getline` and `std::string`:

```
std::string row_text;
std::vector<std::string> grid;
while (std::getline(myReadFile, row_text))
{
  grid.push_back(row_text);
}
```

The `std::string` can be accessed using array notation.